Error "Detected a ZipFile object in the image heap" when compiling with GraalVM Native Image
I am encountering the error
Error: Detected a ZipFile object in the image heap. A ZipFile object
contains pointers to unmanaged C memory and file descriptors, and
these resources are no longer available at image runtime. If these
objects should not be stored in the image heap, you can use

When compiling my application with GraalVM Native Image. I am using Java 21 and GraalVM 21. Additionally, I have used the GraalVM agent to generate reflection configuration files and other necessary files. Despite my attempts, I have not been able to identify the source of the problem. Here is what I have tried so far
I tried using the --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.jar.JarFile option to trace the instantiation of the ZipFile class. When running this command during the native image compilation, the classes instantiating JarFile should appear in the console, but this information did not appear.
I ran the command grep -r "ZipFile" /path/to/project, and the terminal returned that the ZipFile class is found in a .jar file in the directory /target/my-app.jar. This suggests that the ZipFile class is being used in some dependency of the project or in code not directly visible. This JAR file is from my app.
But i used the command grep -r "ZipFile" src/, and nothing was returned in the terminal, indicating that the problem may be in an external dependency and not directly in the source code...
How can I identify which dependency is using the ZipFile class and, consequently, resolve the "Detected a ZipFile object in the image heap" error during compilation with GraalVM Native Image?

Maybe try mkdir .../target/tmp; cd .../target/tmp; jar xf ../my-app.jar; grep -r ZipFile . and see which class contains it.

Thanks for the suggestion! I was able to identify some dependencies and i am in the process of removing them while ensuring the project still builds correctly

@k314159 I couldn't make progress on this issue because the dependencies that were listed (UrlJarFile, NestedJarFile$JarEntryInputStream, NestedFileSystem, NestedFileSystemProvider) are essential for the functioning of Spring Boot. As far as I can tell, it's neither possible nor recommended to remove them from the project, as it would compromise the basic functionality of Spring Boot
